# Wordpress - how to edit homepage

Tags: wordpress

I've just had a website converted for me to Wordpress but the guy who did it has now disappeared!

I just need to get started with it but have hit some major obstacles. My home page is a series of blocks with images and text that respond very nicely to different devices. Trouble is when I go to Pages then Home, I'm faced with a completely blank edit box. Two hours of searching to find where these blocks are and how to edit them has failed.

Any help please!

Comment: Trouble it when I go to Pages the Home, I'm faced with a completely blank edit box. Please correct your phrase so it makes sense. I read it, but I can't figure out your problem. Of course, you need to be logged it, to your admin area of WordPress to edit stuff. In addition, that logged in users needs to have sufficcient access rights to access the posts.

Comment: What does "logged it" mean?

Comment: I'm logged in as Admin. I can edit any page apart from the Home page which appears as blank.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up your theme customizer and at the very bottom you can chose a static front page. Here's where you settle this.
2. Go to Pages in the panel. Open that specific page "Home" and look which template who has been chosen for this page. Perhaps you'll find the right template.
3. However, it could be hard coded  directly in the doc/file itself. Open up your text editor and search for a template i.e home.php or frontpage.php or something similar. Open up in text editor to see.

Answer (score 0):

After another few hours of trial and error, the front page text is in a few places! Some of it is in posts, specifically the "blocks" containing text and images in paragraphs. Other parts can be found by going to Appearance | Editor then choosing Static Front Page. I've yet to find out exactly how these are made to appear on the Home page but I guess I'll get there with experimentation.